# Potassium carbonate and water/alcohol/toluene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Recently I did a distillation. At a certain point an azeotropic mixture of alcohol, water and toluene evaporated and was caught in a beaker with anhydrous potassium carbonate. I had to shake it and then pour it back into the reaction mixture (while filtering out the solid).

Why did I have to catch it in a $\ce{K2CO3}$-mixture?

(The product was diethyladipate)

Comment: Was it simply a drying agent? I can't imagine it reacting with one of the solvents...

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The synthesis you are referring to is outlined [here](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0264). Potassium Carbonate acts as a drying agent as you said as the later part of the distillation requires a specific temperature to remove the toluene and alcohol.

The water comes from the concentrated sulphuric acid solution added with apidic acid. The residue is also rinsed with alcohol which is a strong indicator that water needs to be removed.